# A red line indicating current timestamp in Thunderbird's Lightning

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

Do you know if there is a way to make the red line appear in Lightning to show current timestamp in the calendar(week view)? Thx.

PS. Thunderbird v. 7.0.1. Ubuntu v. 11.10.

Comment: What red line are you referring to?  The current day is indicated by a pale yellow/orange bar throughout the entire day.

Comment: You refer to the current day, whereas I need an indicator(as a red line) of current **time** within a day. Some calendar apps have that feature.

Comment: There is such a red line in my newly installed Ligthning (it had disappeared from Thunderbird, probably through updates). Unfortunately it doesn't move as time passes. I have to manually refresh the page. But this SO question told me what it is! :)

Answer (score 2):

I second this one.  When I glance at the calendar I would love to be able to see where I am in the day, right now. (No thinking required)

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you will find is [Timeline](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/timeline/) which puts a status bar at the bottom of the page, and has the "Now" marker and todays events.

Comment: I tried that one earlier, its crap. I guess there is no polished plugin yet.